# configure squid to act as transparent proxy

Tags: proxy, squid, transparent-proxy

I have configured squid to support transparency using this command

```
./configure --enable-ipfw-transparent --enable-ssl
```

I have started squid, is there any other configuration that i need to add so that all web requests do not bypass the proxy

I have already setup the squid machine to have transparent proxying on 176.16.1.197:8000

The machine I have setup for squid is not running as the gateway to the internet, How do I setup so that all http requests go through to squid?

Do i have to use IP tables? where do i setup the IP tables? on the gateway? or squid machine?

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure `squid.conf` to enable the transparent proxy mode. Then, you need to configure your firewall to redirect all web traffic through the proxy. You can look up the information [elsewhere](https://serverfault.com/questions/8340/transparent-proxy-with-squid-iptables).

Comment: What if I have not installed the squid machine as the gateway? How can i get only the web requests from port 80

Comment: You need to make the firewall changes on your gateway. I have such a configuration. My router redirects traffic to the squid proxy which is on another machine. The only web traffic it allows thru is the one from the squid proxy.