# some way to make the proxy transparent

Tags: routing, proxy, docker

I'm working at a company that requires a proxy server for connecting to the internet. 
Unfortunately I have to deal quite much with VMs and docker containers. It's really hard for me to build and test them locally because I have to enter that proxy in all tools (apt, docker itself, tools during docker build, tools on container runtime, ...) that are involved. Sometimes it's not even possible to set up a proxy explicitely.

Now I'm thinking about some tool that I could run as a virtual machine and acts as a network gateway, forwarding the traffic to the proxy (the proxy supports HTTP Connect).

I didn't find anything like this via google. Does anyone here know about a tool (or some iptables magic) to do this?

Comment: @Hanginoninquietdesperation Well it's not _really_ a try to circumvent the policy, just to work around the need to enter the proxy in all his containers, sending traffic to one "aggregator" to forward to the proxy, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transparent Proxy with Squid / iptables](http://serverfault.com/questions/8340/transparent-proxy-with-squid-iptables)

Comment: Create a VM with two network interfaces (I'm going for Linux here). Enable port forwarding and NAT, use iptables to force traffic on port 80 (or whatever) to use the upstream proxy server. Add this VM as gateway for your containers / VMs. (Added as comment because: short summary).